# Открытие ссылок из iframe в родительском окне

Tags: javascript, iframe, link

Здравствуйте,

На родительскую страницу через iframe вставляю html. При этом во вставляемом html содержится несколько ссылок. Необходимо, чтобы эти ссылки открывались не в окне iframe, а вместо всей родительской страницы.

Код родительской страницы

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<title>tindirindis</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
  <iframe src="EdgeAnimate/nav_programs.html" width="555" height="36">Ваш браузер не поддерживает встроенные фреймы!</iframe>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Код вставляемого html, что создан в EdgeAnimate, и его файл JavaScript

```js
/**
 * Adobe Edge: symbol definitions
 */
(function($, Edge, compId){
//images folder
var im='images/';

var fonts = {};
var opts = {
    'gAudioPreloadPreference': 'auto',

    'gVideoPreloadPreference': 'auto'
};
var resources = [
];
var symbols = {
"stage": {
    version: "4.0.0",
    minimumCompatibleVersion: "4.0.0",
    build: "4.0.0.359",
    baseState: "Base State",
    scaleToFit: "none",
    centerStage: "both",
    initialState: "Base State",
    gpuAccelerate: false,
    resizeInstances: false,
    content: {
            dom: [
            {
                id: 'button_5',
                type: 'rect',
                rect: ['0', '0','auto','auto','auto', 'auto']
            }],
            symbolInstances: [
            {
                id: 'button_5',
                symbolName: 'button_5',
                autoPlay: {

                }
            }
            ]
        },
    states: {
        "Base State": {
            "${_Stage}": [
                ["color", "background-color", 'rgba(39,0,255,0.00)'],
                ["style", "width", '555px'],
                ["style", "height", '36px'],
                ["style", "overflow", 'hidden']
            ]
        }
    },
    timelines: {
        "Default Timeline": {
            fromState: "Base State",
            toState: "",
            duration: 0,
            autoPlay: true,
            timeline: [
            ]
        }
    }
},
"button_5": {
    version: "4.0.0",
    minimumCompatibleVersion: "4.0.0",
    build: "4.0.0.359",
    baseState: "Base State",
    scaleToFit: "none",
    centerStage: "none",
    initialState: "Base State",
    gpuAccelerate: false,
    resizeInstances: false,
    content: {
            dom: [
                {
                    id: '_02_2',
                    type: 'image',
                    rect: ['0px', '0', '555px', '36px', 'auto', 'auto'],
                    fill: ['rgba(0,0,0,0)', 'images/02_2.png', '0px', '0px']
                },
                {
                    rect: ['126px', '5px', '133px', '26px', 'auto', 'auto'],
                    id: 'Rectangle1Copy4',
                    stroke: [0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)', 'none'],
                    type: 'rect',
                    fill: ['rgba(192,192,192,0.00)']
                }
            ],
            symbolInstances: [
            ]
        },
    states: {
        "Base State": {
            "${__02_2}": [
                ["style", "left", '0px'],
                ["style", "overflow", 'visible']
            ],
            "${symbolSelector}": [
                ["style", "height", '36px'],
                ["style", "width", '555px']
            ],
            "${_Rectangle1Copy4}": [
                ["color", "background-color", 'rgba(192,192,192,0.00)'],
                ["style", "top", '5px'],
                ["style", "height", '26px'],
                ["style", "width", '133px']
            ]
        }
    },
    timelines: {
        "Default Timeline": {
            fromState: "Base State",
            toState: "",
            duration: 0,
            autoPlay: true,
            timeline: [
            ]
        }
    }
}
};


Edge.registerCompositionDefn(compId, symbols, fonts, resources, opts);

/**
 * Adobe Edge DOM Ready Event Handler
 */
$(window).ready(function() {
     Edge.launchComposition(compId);
});
})(jQuery, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-1603117873");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
 <title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="nav_programs_edgePreload.js"></script>
    <style>
        .edgeLoad-EDGE-1603117873 { visibility:hidden; }
    </style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
 <div id="Stage" class="EDGE-1603117873">
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь, атрибут `target` HTML-элемента `<a>` это то, что вам нужно. В частности, ссылкам, которые должны открываться в родительском окне, нужно добавить

```
target="_top"
```

Подробнее про `target`: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp